# Spherically Distributed Random Vector Is Isotropic

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I'm trying to prove that spherically distributed random vector $X \sim \text{Unif}(\sqrt{n}S^{n-1})$ is isotropic and for that I want to prove
$$
\mathbb{E} \langle X,x \rangle^2 = \| x \|_2 ^2 \;\;\;\;\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n 
$$
Now if I can show that $\langle X,x \rangle = \langle X, \| x \|_2 \, e_i \rangle$ (with $e_i$ being the vectors from ONB for $\mathbb{R}^n$), then I now how to finish the proof. But does this actually hold and why?

I am aware that this problem has been discussed (for example [Why uniform distribution on sphere of radius $\sqrt n$ isotropic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427040/why-uniform-distribution-on-sphere-of-radius-sqrt-n-isotropic?rq=1)), but this point was also explained by "the rotational invariance of the distribution of $X$" - what does this concretely mean?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is a group that acts on a set $E$, and if $X$ is an $E$-valued random variable, we say that the distribution of $X$ is $G$-invariant if for all $g \in G$, $gX$ and $X$ have the same law (provided, of course, that no measurability problems occur, but this doesn't happen in usual situations).

For example, if $E$ is a finite set, and if $G$ is the group of permutations of $E$, then an $E$-valued random variable $X$ is $G$-invariant if and only if it is uniform on $E$.

Saying that a random vector $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is *rotationally-invariant* means that it is $\mathbf{SO}(n,\mathbb{R})$ invariant in the above sense, i.e. for any rotation $R$, $RX$ and $X$ have the same law.

Now, the argument is the following: let $x$ and $y$ be two vectors that have the same length, and let $X$ be a rotationally-invariant vector. Then $\langle X,x\rangle$ and $\langle X,y\rangle$ have same law.

Indeed, let $R$ be a rotation that sends $x$ on $y$. We therefore have $\langle X,x\rangle$ (because the rotations leave the scalar product unchanged), and so $\langle X,x\rangle = \langle RX, Rx\rangle = \langle RX, y\rangle$. Now, by assumption, $RX$ and $X$ have the same law, so $\langle RX, y\rangle$ and $\langle X,y\rangle$ have the same law, and therefore $\langle X,x\rangle$ and $\langle X,y\rangle$ have the same law.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I was hoping there might have been a more straightforward linear algebra argument, but I guess that was too much to hope for... Thanks again!

Comment: At what point would you have hoped for more linear algebra?